# VPS is unaccessible through ssh and cant connect website

Tags: django, ssh, vps

the problem is the connection to my vps is lost on daily basis multiple times like 20 mins. When the server is down i can't connect website so i get the error:

```
Err connection timed out.
```

and i try connecting through ssh and it outputs a log:

```
Connection refused.
```

Nothing more nothing less i should solve this because it causes lots of trouble the only solution i came up with its restarting from the server provider site. But this happens frequently not one in a month or a year it happens 10 times a day. How should i debug the problem or how can i find a real solution.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit**

The output of ssh -vvv root@ip:

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname *ip is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to *ip [*ip] port 22.
debug1: connect to address *ip port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host *ip port 22: Connection refused
```

Apache error.log

```
[Sun Oct 17 13:59:41.104024 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2883:tid 139903188997888] [remote some_ip:53604] Bad Request: /iframe2/news/kurallar/
[Sun Oct 17 13:59:41.109194 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2883:tid 139903071426304] [remote some_ip:48318] Bad Request: /iframe2/news/kurallar/
[Sun Oct 17 14:10:08.136701 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2883:tid 139903071426304] [remote my_ip:24816] Not Found: /favicon.ico
[Sun Oct 17 14:19:34.339115 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2882:tid 139903302818752] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseEventLoop.__del__ of <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 526, in __del__
NameError: name 'ResourceWarning' is not defined
[Sun Oct 17 14:19:34.517419 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3319:tid 140614344002496] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Oct 17 14:19:34.517583 2021] [core:notice] [pid 3319:tid 140614344002496] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

/var/log/auth.log

```
Oct 17 21:15:01 my_name sshd[1365]: Invalid user pi from 94.3.213.149 port 42290
Oct 17 21:15:01 my_name sshd[1364]: Invalid user pi from 94.3.213.149 port 42286
Oct 17 21:15:01 my_name sshd[1365]: Connection closed by invalid user pi 94.3.213.149 port 42290 [preauth]
Oct 17 21:15:01 my_name sshd[1364]: Connection closed by invalid user pi 94.3.213.149 port 42286 [preauth]
Oct 17 22:00:38 my_name sshd[1628]: Invalid user user from 212.193.30.32 port 39410
Oct 17 22:00:38 my_name sshd[1628]: Received disconnect from 212.193.30.32 port 39410:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Oct 17 22:00:38 my_name sshd[1628]: Disconnected from invalid user user 212.193.30.32 port 39410 [preauth]
```

I get lots of these inputs and shutdowns in the log the name 'pi' and the ip is not me. Do these connections affect the website or leak any information of the user.

There are gaps in the closed times when i could not connect to the server.

The closed times the /var/log/syslog prints these:

```
Oct 18 08:27:08 my_name kernel: [53593.658210] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC={mac_addr} SRC={some_ip} DST={my_ip} LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=241 ID=31782 PROTO=TCP SPT=47415 DPT=24634 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Oct 18 08:35:01 my_name CRON[2854]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Oct 18 08:45:01 my_name CRON[2860]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Oct 18 08:49:48 my_name kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.15.0-158-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-051) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)) #166-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 17 19:37:52 UTC 2021 (Ubuntu 4.15.0-158.166-generic 4.15.18)
```

Comment: Do you have any logs? Any thing that you think triggers the crash?

Comment: I don't have any information about why this crashes i don't know where to monitor the crash i asked server provider and they told the issue is not on them.

Comment: First thing you need to do is configure logging in all processes that you can, write them all somewhere that persists outside of the VPS and use them to debug if your app is the cause

Comment: try ssh in verbose mode (`ssh -vvv user@server`) and then add here some more info it will show

Comment: In apache logs i see lots of different user ip like from china india bangladesh australia. This should not happen since my website is not socially accessible. I look it up and some of them are reported. This can be the problem?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko i added the output log of the input you provided.

Comment: You're trying to connect the host `ip`, that wont work. But if you replaced the real name in your example log, then there is still the  `Connection refused` error. The server doesn't accept a connection

Comment: On the server, is there something installed like `failed2ban` ? Try a look into `/var/log/auth.log` and `/var/log/fail2ban.log`

Comment: @jeb i added the some of the auth.log output in the question, and i dont have failed2ban or the log file you mention.

Comment: If there are gaps in auth.log and even the harmless attacks stop (if you disabled passwords for ssh), then it seems that the ssh server stopped/hang. Could be visible in `/var/log/syslog` or try to monitor your system with something like [prometheus](https://prometheus.io/)

Comment: hi @jeb i added the closed times system response in the syslog to the question. Thanks for your guidances.